# Microsoft.XMLDOM xml.load xml.parseError.errorCode different result for another user

Tags: delphi-2009, xmldom

I am putting some Delphi 2007 Win32 code through a QA test step.

Strangely, the testing person is getting a different result than me with same input file.

The code section of interest is:

```
xml := CreateOleObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM') as IXMLDOMDocument;

xml.async := False;
xml.load(odlgImport.FileName);

if xml.parseError.errorCode <> 0 then
begin
     bValid := False;
     showmessage('xml.parseError.errorCode: ' + inttostr(xml.parseError.errorCode) );
end
```

I don't really understand how this code can give a different result for the testing person, than me, when we are using the same input file and the same environment and server.

Any comments or assistance much appreciated !

Comment: Hard to diagnose without knowing the actual environment setup. Are you absolutely sure you are using the same input file? What is `odlgImport` and what is its `FileName` actually being set to? My guess would be that `Microsoft.XMLDOM` resolves to different versions of MSXML on your two systems.

Comment: odlgImport is a FileOpen dialog component ... Filename is the returned result from this FileOpen dialog .. which is full path and filename to the XML file ..

Comment: OK, but what about the other thing I said.  Did you check which version of MSXML that the `Microsoft.XMLDOM` progid resolves to on each machine?  There are multiple versions of MSXML floating around.

Comment: Strangely, the testing person reports that the process is working for them today, one day later ..  hmm ..

Comment: I will look into what version of Microsoft.XMLDOM is used ... and progid ...  Thanks for your comment !    The tester was getting message 'Invalid file format' from other processes late yesterday also ..     Maybe Microsoft.XMLDOM was unavailable to her ... somehow ... at that stage ..

Comment: Sounds more like maybe the XML file was just corrupted, or possibly still being written to, at the time the parse was being invoked.

Comment: Am thinking with has turned out to be a different database "system parameter" value between development level DB and QAP level DB and different sections of code execute based on the database "system parameter" value setting ..    This took a while to find/determine ...  OK - perhaps Microsoft.XMLDOM is solid and reliable after all ..  (I had perhaps jumped to a wrong problem diagnosis) ..